# Why does text duplicate itself in Android Jelly Bean Mail?

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3

OK, I have a new Samsung Galaxy S III, updated to Jelly Bean 4.1.1.

While Gmail works fine, when I send messages using one of my Web server's accounts, the message text duplicates itself in the body of the message. So:

. The accounts are set up as IMAP, with SSL on.

Any guidance to configuring the handset or my server to address this?

I do not have this problem using a desktop Mac or PC email client, or an iPhone.

Comment: Did you intend to include a screen shot? Your post seems to be missing some information.

Comment: No need for a screen shot. You check sent messages and the text inside is duplicated. Also when I hit return in this forum, it posts the message rather than move to the next paragraph.

Comment: Example as follows: Test


Sent via the Samsung Galaxy S™III  Test


Sent via the Samsung Galaxy S™III

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information. Comments are, by their nature, impermanent.